# How can I refer to a nose in a pleasing manner?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to figure out a word that describes a nose in a pleasing way. I.e.

> The smell of freshly baked bread wafted into the **__** of passers by.

*Nasal cavity* — too scientific, *beak/snout* — too animalistic, *nose* — too boring.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with *nose*, but you can always use something non-physical, like *notice* or *attention*.

Comment: Might the word _nostrils_ would work for you? Or would that smell too rank?

Comment: Or leave the details out and have the aroma waft over the people rather than into some specific part of them.

Comment: The aroma was stuffed up their facial protusions. ???

Comment: Baking bread bouquet blew bystanders' bills.

Comment: I thought Loudon Wainright III handled it nicely in his song "Dead Skunk in the Middle of the Road": "You don't have to look and you don't have to see/'Cause you can feel it in your olfactory."

Comment: ...wafted into the *aromatic senses* of the passers by.

Answer (score 7):

While *nose* is indeed ok, and perhaps is best among it and its synonyms, you might metonymically or synecdochically use the word *face* instead.  For example,

> The smell of freshly baked bread wafted into the smiling, uplifted faces of passersby.

Comment: Well done. I can see their noses tipping up to capture the smell.

Comment: That's a nice one.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with *nose*. It is a perfectly polite, well brought up and pleasant word. It has no unpleasant connotations that I am aware of. If you really really don't want to use it, you could wax a little lyrical like so

> The smell of freshly baked bread tickled the olfactory nerves of passers by.

This, however, is stilted and sounds pretentious. My friendly thesaurus (whom I recommend you befriend yourself) [suggests](http://thesaurus.com/browse/nose?s=t):

> adenoids, beak, bill*, horn, muzzle, nares, nostrils, olfactory nerves, proboscis, schnoz, smeller, sneezer, sniffer, snoot, snout, snuffer, whiffer

Of all these words, the best is the simple *nose*. I don't know why you are prejudiced against it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go a little more fanciful, yet, and say:

> The smell of freshly baked bread wafted into the **deepest pleasure senses and happy memories** of the passers by.

Comment: I prefer *nose*. Any alternative sounds as if it had been written by Amanda McKittrick Ross.

Comment: @TheFrog - to each his own (and the author's name is Ros, not Ross) :-)

Comment: Yes, you are correct Amanda McKittrick Ros was her pen name. She probably found her real name, Ross, as dull as the word *nose*.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that nose is "on the nose' ? Just being a little nosy. I think "wafted" is a rather ordinary word that is overused. I would prefer something a bit more imaginative, for example, the smell of bread tantalized passers by.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to say is that you want a "cuter" substitution for nose. While not as commonly used, I think the word "neb" might suit you here.

> The smell of freshly baked bread wafted into the nebs of passers by.